# Replacing document.createElement() with React.createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript library which uses `document.createElement()` which creates an `HTMLElement`
I want to create a react library with the same functionality.
My idea was to replace the `document.createElement()` with `React.createElement()` .

So , the original code which was something like

```
    this.myElement = document.createElement("input");
   /* some stuff happens here due only after which the followig code is run */
    this.myElement.className = "someClassName";
    this.myElement.style.display = "block";
    this.myElement.appendChild(someElement);
```

will become

```
this.myElement = React.createElement("input");
this.myElement.props.className = "someClassName";
this.myElement.props.style.display = "block"; // Props is read only at this point
this.myElement.appendChild(someReactElement); // This doesn't work either
```

The problem here is that props is a read only property in react , also appendChild doesn't work that way in. So changing it after  `React.createElement("input")` is not possible. I can create the props object before each createElement call based on the original code but it significantly reduces reusability of the existing code base. Is there a way around that can be used to bypass this issue in react ?

Edit : I know I can pass children and props during the time I call React.createElement however , it reduces my ability to copy paste and reuse  the existing code base . The question is specific about changing props and appeding child after the React.createElement call

Comment: Create a `props` object and pass that as the 2nd argument of the `createElement` function. `React.createElement('input', props, children)`

Comment: out of interest, why are you trying to directly call `React.createElement` outside of a React component? (And it's usually easier to write JSX than to directly call `React.createElement` as well.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond. as mentioned in the question I have an existing library which uses HTMLElement created using document.createELement  . I am trying to convert the  library in react . The library is large , so creating a react library in JSX requires much more efffort . I am trying to minimise my efforts by figuring a way to minimise changes

Comment: OK - but that's not really how to do it. React is fundamentally about creating components. You can certainly convert a non-React UI to a React one piece by piece, but each step involves writing React components. It doesn't make sense to call React.createElement outside of a React component, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Create a props object and pass that as the 2nd argument of the createElement function. Follow this-

```
const props = {
    className: 'someClassName',
    style: {
        display: 'block',
        width: '100%'
    }
}

React.createElement('input', props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). You can pass the props (and children) in the function.